# Execute background task after local notification was received in didReceiveLocalNotification:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, uibackgroundtask

Is it possible to execute a background task with `[application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"LOG_STUFF" expirationHandler:^{}];` in the `AppDelegate`'s method `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is in the foreground, yes!

If your app is suspended (already in the background), the app has to be brought to the foreground for the "`didReceiveLocalNotification:`" method to fire and for you to be able to begin your background task.

Check out [Apple's documentation for "`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) method for more details on how to properly use this API.